# Dynamically size images in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My goal is to have a list of items each item has an image beside it whose size is proportional to some number from a dataset. For example, a list of countries which includes an image of a person whose size is proportional to the population.

How can I dynamically specify the size of an image based on data from the dataset?
Two approaches which don't seem to work:
(1) specify an expression for the image size (that doesn't seem to fit).
(2) tell the image to fit container and set the size of the container to an expression.

I don't want to resort to storing 100 images of varying sizes.
Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the "Padding" values of a cell or an image. These can be set with an expression, and will be the white space around your image.

For example, set right padding to
`=RowNumber("DataSet").ToString() &"pt"`
and you will get an image that gets smaller on each row.

Hope this helps...